# How to remove Windows 7 if I have installed with Wubi?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

So, I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 with a windows installer (Wubi) and I want to delete Windows 7 completely leaving Ubuntu alone. Does anyone know how to do that without having to do everything all over again?

Comment: wilf: I think in this case this guide will not work because Clint used Wubi. this does not make a separate partition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend (do it at your own risk) to take time and a make fresh install after wiping every possible partition from your HDD. Then you can configure your buntu exactly as you wish, without workarounds etc. Or just let buntu do it for you.